# Inaccurate hamming distance of two strings in binary

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography

I'm trying to calculate the hamming distance between two strings in binary. However I'm not getting the expected output which is 37. Instead I get 33. Can someone explain to me the mistake I'm making?

Here's my code:

```
def to_bin(s):
return ''.join(format(ord(x), 'b') for x in s)
s1 = to_bin('this is a test')
s2 = to_bin('wokka wokka!!!')

def hamming_distance_bin(x,y):
    z = []
    for i,j in zip(x,y):
        z.append(ord(i)^ord(j))
    return z.count(1)



print hamming_distance_bin(s1,s2)
```

The reason I'm using the list above, is so that I could print my xor'd output to manually count the 1's and see where I'm going wrong. But I don't seem to understand!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def to_bin(s):
    return ''.join(format(ord(x), 'b') for x in s)
```

returns a variable-length binary string. You want to output a constant-length one:

```
def to_bin(s):
    return ''.join(format(ord(x), '08b') for x in s)
```

---

FWIW, I'd do:

```
s1 = bytearray(b'this is a test')
s2 = bytearray(b'wokka wokka!!!')

def hamming_distance_bin(x,y):
    return sum(bin(i^j).count("1") for i,j in zip(x,y))

hamming_distance_bin(s1,s2)
```

because `bytearray` is neater than calling `ord` all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `bin().zfill(8)` for each character, which fixes the problem you are having.

The answer above is good code; another way just to get the point across would be:

```
def hamming(str1, str2):

    score = 0

    for (a, b) in izip(str1, str2):
        a_bits = bin(ord(a))[2:].zfill(8)
        b_bits = bin(ord(b))[2:].zfill(8)

        score += sum(bx != by for bx, by in izip(a_bits, b_bits))
    return score
```

The benefit of this, I suppose, would be that the string to binary conversion is built into the function itself.